# Issues with setting up Ionic for Moodle mobile app development

Tags: ionic-framework, moodle-mobile

***Issue:***

I am currently experiencing issues with getting Ionic set up for Moodle mobile app development.

***What have I tried?***

I am currently following the [Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2) documentation.

However, when I run the command `npm run setup` I get the warning:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for mathjax@2.7.7 (sha512-OOl0B2/0tSJAtAZarXnQuLDBLgTNRqiI9VqHTQzPsxf4okT2iIpDrvaklK9x2QEMD1sDj4yRn11Ygci41DxMAQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.`
```

It takes really long to extract on the retry.

**copy of the issue.**
[image: Attached]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Only having this issue on my windows install though. Not a problem on linux.

It freezes on that tarball. To get past it I did the following in moodleapp directory:

npm cache clean --force
npm install mathjax@3
npm run setup

...will see how the rest of the environment setup goes.